# Using functions inside Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system with the function: `Solve`.
But I am not able to use functions within the `Solve`, for example the ABS function. Why does it take a long time to calculate.

Example:

```
X = 10;
a = 1, b = 2, c = 0;
Solve [
  Tec == a * b * c
  Ret == Sqrt [Abs [Tec-Xe]],
  Val == Tec * ret,
  {Tec, Ret, Val}]
```

Comment: Can you explain me why?

Comment: @Artes I have personally asked you not to make comments like that.  I ask one more time:  *please, stop.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Sometimes I can't see a better way to tell them: "Read your question and check if it's correctly posed" . First (s)he uses `Ret`, then `ret`, there is something like `Xe`  which was assumed to be `X`, there are no boolean operators or a list of equations, etc.  All that is quite enough to delete such a question before closing.   By the way the system of equations is on the level of first years of an elementary school. So my dig was quite reasonable.  I still try to make this site better however this appears to be constantly more and more difficult.  That's all I can do.

Comment: @Artes Simple: *avoid ad hominem attacks.*  It is OK to point out that code in a question is entirely invalid syntax (you and I have both seen far worse than this one, by the way) and that the OP needs to invest himself in basic familiarity with *Mathematica* coding before posting questions here.  It is *not* OK to state or imply that a user is too stupid to use the software, etc.  Surely you understand the difference.

Comment: You are right. I tring to explain my issue without mathematica. So I do not tried my code. Sorry for that. But my problem keep appear..

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple equations to be solved at the same time you should use `&&`(logical AND) to separate them, like in the second example of the [Solve reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html).

```
xe = 10; a = 1; b = 2; c = 0;
Solve[tec == a*b*c && ret == Sqrt[Abs[tec - xe]] && 
  val == tec*ret, {tec, ret, val}]
```

I would also suggest using variables with the first letter lowercase to differentiate them from  built‐in Wolfram Language Objects.

Comment: What is the diference between comman and && (logical AND) ?

Solve[{expr1,expr2,…},vars] is equivalent to Solve[expr1&&expr2&&…,vars].

Comment: @Green Yes, I believe the two forms are functionally equivalent within `Solve`.